# How do I apply CSS styles using jQuery to a textarea field in rails forms?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, html

I'm newbie to Rails and HTML5.
I would like to make a form more stylish by using jQuery. 
Here's the code:

View:

```
<textarea name="styled-textarea" id="styled" onfocus="this.value=''; setbg('#e5fff3');" onblur="setbg('white')">Enter your comment here... </textarea>
```

js:

```
function setbg(color)
{
document.getElementById("styled").style.background=color
}
```

This textarea should belong to this form:

```
<%= form_for([@post, @post.comments.build]) do |f| %>
    <%= f.label :commenter %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :commenter %><br /><br />
    <%= f.text_area :body %>
    <%= f.submit %><br />
<% end %>
```

How do I apply same CSS styles as the textarea's on my `<%= f.text_area :body %>`?

Any help will be really appreciated! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a custom id for your form field, like this:

```
<%= f.text_area :body, id: 'styled' %>
```

Jquery

```
$("#styled").on('focus', function(){
  $(this).val(''); 
   setbg('#e5fff3');
});

$("#styled").on('blur', function(){
  setbg('white')
});
```

instead Jquery, is better use css

```
#styled:focus {
  background: #e5fff3;
}

#styled {
  background: white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please do not use inline JS!
But use JQuery and keep the actual `f.text_area`,doing something like that:

```
<script>
  $('youtextarea_id')
  .on('focus', function() {
     $(this).val(''); 
     setbg('#e5fff3');
  }
  .on('blur', function() {
     setbg('white');
  };
</script>
```

the ID is generated by rails and you can see it in the generated html. You can always change it with `f.text_area :body, id: 'another_id'`

Comment: I used CSS instead. Thanks for the help anyway!:)